# How to install .crt files(SSL) on web logic server?

Tags: web, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

I have CA certified chain of certificates each with '.crt' extention. Can some one please tell on how to install them on web logic server 11g/12c? Please note that I do not have keystore. I just need to  import those .crt files on to web logic server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WebLogic Server uses keystores for ssl certificates and keys. Read this [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/blogbypuneeth/steps-to-create-a-jks-keystore-using-key-and-crt-files) to know how to create one, import your crt file.